# AveragePooling2D doesn't recognize a dtype

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have a problem with AveragePooling2D:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, AveragePooling2D
import keras.backend as K
import math

K.clear_session()

base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(150, 150, 3)))
x = base_model.outputs
x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(8, 8))(x)
```

I get an error:

> ---
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in
>   **call**(self, inputs, **kwargs)
>       617 
>       618             # Actually call the layer, collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
>   --> 619             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>       620             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
>       621
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/pooling.py in
>   call(self, inputs)
>       156                                         strides=self.strides,
>       157                                         padding=self.padding,
>   --> 158                                         data_format=self.data_format)
>       159         return output
>       160
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/pooling.py in
>   _pooling_function(self, inputs, pool_size, strides, padding, data_format)
>       273                           padding, data_format):
>       274         output = K.pool2d(inputs, pool_size, strides,
>   --> 275                           padding, data_format, pool_mode='avg')
>       276         return output
>       277
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py
>   in pool2d(x, pool_size, strides, padding, data_format, pool_mode)
>   3643         raise ValueError('Unknown data_format: ' +
>   str(data_format))    3644 
>   -> 3645     x, tf_data_format = _preprocess_conv2d_input(x, data_format)    3646     padding = _preprocess_padding(padding)
>   3647     if tf_data_format == 'NHWC':
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py
>   in _preprocess_conv2d_input(x, data_format)    3202         A tensor. 
>   3203     """
>   -> 3204     if dtype(x) == 'float64':    3205         x = tf.cast(x, 'float32')    3206     tf_data_format = 'NHWC'
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py
>   in dtype(x)
>       640     ```
>       641     """
>   --> 642     return x.dtype.base_dtype.name
>       643 
>       644
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

but if I print(x) this is the result I get:

> tf.Tensor 'mixed10/concat:0' shape=(?, 3, 3, 2048) dtype=float32

So basically "x" has a dtype which is float32 but AveragePooling2D doesn't recognize it as I understand it correctly. Can anyone point me out where to look to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the 's':

```
x = base_model.output
```

That's because `outputs` gives you a list of outputs. As you only have one in this case, `output` works fine for you. You'd have to select from this list otherwise.